# Find the zero values in one dataframe and replace with the nearest datetime reading from another data frame

Tags: r

I have no idea if im going about this the right way but im struggling to find a solution.

I have two data frames these are taken directly from a MySQL database `df1` and `df2` sometimes the  `df1$start_weight` is zero but in we have the value recorded in `df2` (`df2` records values every 10 mins). What I want to do is search for any zero values in `df1$start_weight` and add the value from `df2$Weight` to `df1$start_weight`. My thought would be to use the nearest datetime to match the values.

`df1` =

```
     balance    id             logdate         start_weight end_weight target_weight
1             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-10 18:00:07         2916       2916          2805
2             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-11 18:00:22         2719       2806          2805
3             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-12 18:00:27         2636       2805          2805
4             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-13 18:00:26            0       2807          2805
5             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-14 18:00:27         2618       2804          2805
6             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-15 18:00:13            0       2807          2805
7             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-16 18:00:30         2589       2805          2805
```

`df2` =

```
     balance      id             logdate            Weight
30              2 VV001-01510 2018-05-10 17:50:03   2919
31              2 VV001-01510 2018-05-10 18:00:03   2916
32              2 VV001-01510 2018-05-10 18:10:04   2913
174             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-11 17:50:03   2721
175             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-11 18:00:03   2719
176             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-11 18:10:03   2812
316             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-12 17:50:03   2638
317             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-12 18:00:04   2636
318             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-12 18:10:03   2810
```

What I have so far is:

```
for (x in 1:nrow(watering)) {
  if (watering[x,]$start_weight == '0') {
    print(x)  #used to check the first bit worked
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post you desired output so we can help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using a *rolling join to nearest* and a subsequent *update join* of `df1`:

```
library(data.table)
tmp <- setDT(df2)[setDT(df1)[start_weight == 0], on = .(balance, id, logdate), 
                  roll = "nearest"]
df1[tmp, on = .(balance, id, logdate), start_weight := Weight]
df1
```

> ```
>    rn balance          id             logdate start_weight end_weight target_weight
> 1:  1       2 VV001-01510 2018-05-10 18:00:07         2916       2916          2805
> 2:  2       2 VV001-01510 2018-05-11 18:00:22         2719       2806          2805
> 3:  3       2 VV001-01510 2018-05-12 18:00:27         2636       2805          2805
> 4:  4       2 VV001-01510 2018-05-13 18:00:26         2810       2807          2805
> 5:  5       2 VV001-01510 2018-05-14 18:00:27         2618       2804          2805
> 6:  6       2 VV001-01510 2018-05-15 18:00:13         2810       2807          2805
> 7:  7       2 VV001-01510 2018-05-16 18:00:30         2589       2805          2805
> ```

Please, note that `logdate` is expected to be of class `POSIXct` for *rolling to nearest*.

#### Data

```
df1 <- readr::read_table(
" rn      balance    id             logdate         start_weight end_weight target_weight
  1             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-10 18:00:07         2916       2916          2805
  2             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-11 18:00:22         2719       2806          2805
  3             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-12 18:00:27         2636       2805          2805
  4             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-13 18:00:26            0       2807          2805
  5             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-14 18:00:27         2618       2804          2805
  6             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-15 18:00:13            0       2807          2805
  7             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-16 18:00:30         2589       2805          2805")

df2 <- readr::read_table(
"rn       balance      id             logdate            Weight
30              2 VV001-01510 2018-05-10 17:50:03   2919
31              2 VV001-01510 2018-05-10 18:00:03   2916
32              2 VV001-01510 2018-05-10 18:10:04   2913
174             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-11 17:50:03   2721
175             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-11 18:00:03   2719
176             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-11 18:10:03   2812
316             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-12 17:50:03   2638
317             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-12 18:00:04   2636
318             2 VV001-01510 2018-05-12 18:10:03   2810")
```

Comment: I got a error when running this but found that my logdate colomn class was set as character once changed to as.POSIXct all worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

Using `lubridate`:

```
df1$start_weight[df1$start_weight==0]<-
  df2$Weight[df2$id==df1$id[df1$start_weight==0] & 
    floor_date(df2$logdate, "10 mins")==floor_date(df1$logdate[df1$start_weight==0], "10 mins")]
```

Here's what's happening here: you find all the cases where start_weight is 0, then you compare them to all the cases in df2 where id is the same, the the logdate rounded down to the 10 minutes equals the rounded date-time of df2.